# Unable to find name/value seperator

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a simple command. A flying minecart. To do so, I put it on a bat and made it invisible. My problem is that I have everything put in correctly and it is still not activating. Help?

```
/summon Minecart ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},{ActiveEffects:{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `/summon Minecart ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},{ActiveEffects:{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}}}`

`ActiveEffects` is a list, not a single compound tag:

```
/summon Minecart ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},{ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}]}}
```

`ActiveEffects` should also be in the same compound tag as `Riding` is (the top tag), not a separate one:

```
/summon Minecart ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}]}
```

Unless you're using the newest snapshot, a minecart's name is `MinecartRideable`:

```
/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}]}
```

Unless you're using a version before 1.9, the `Riding` tag no longer exists. You'll need to swap everything around and use the `Passengers` tag:

```
/summon Bat ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:MinecartRideable,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}]}]}
```

Potion effects don't work on a minecart. If you were trying to put it on the bat, then you'd need to do:

```
/summon Bat ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:MinecartRideable}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1000000}]}
```